# Can't link with libtheora on Linux

Tags: linux, ogg-theora

I just add to linker command `-ltheora`
But I still get linker errors `undefined reference to th_info_init`, and libs are installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that `-ltheora` is enough?

I have seen examples which use `-ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg` when linking with that lib.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeap, I forget add `-ltheoraenc -ltheoradec`